# Laravel VueJS testing TypeError: _vm._ssrEscape is not a function

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, mocha.js

I’ve been piecing together a few different tutorials to try and get Mocha tests working for Laravel 7 Vue Components.

I can successfully run a basic test

`expect(0).toBe(0);`

But as soon as I try and mount a component I get the following error

```
TypeError: _vm._ssrEscape is not a function
      at Proxy.render (public/main.js:154:13)
      at VueComponent.Vue._render (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3538:22)
      at VueComponent.updateComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4054:21)
      at Watcher.get (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4465:25)
      at new Watcher (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4454:12)
      at mountComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4061:3)
      at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:8392:10)
      at init (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3112:13)
      at createComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:5958:9)
      at createElm (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:5905:9)
      at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:6455:7)
      at VueComponent.Vue._update (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3933:19)
      at VueComponent.updateComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4054:10)
      at Watcher.get (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4465:25)
      at new Watcher (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4454:12)
      at mountComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4061:3)
```

I’m running Node 12.18.2.

My test file contains

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Counter from '../../resources/js/components/Counter';

describe ('Counter', () => {

    it ('defaults to a count of 0', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(Counter);
    });

});
```

And my component contains

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span class="count" v-text="count"></span>
        <button @click="count++"></button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Counter",
        data () {
            return {
                count: 0
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

The test command is

`mochapack --webpack-config node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js --require tests/Vue/setup.js tests/Vue/**/*.spec.js`

And the setup.js file contains

```
require('jsdom-global')()
global.expect = require('expect');
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I’ve got this working now.

Using parts of this https://dev.to/tuandm/how-to-test-vue-components-with-laravel-mix-and-mocha-3kgc/

Rather than install mcocha-webpack then uninstalling I went straight to installing mochapack

```
npm install --save-dev webpack vue-template-compiler @vue/test-utils mocha mochapack jsdom jsdom-global expect
```